# How does a Collider work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, large-hadron-collider, protons, binding-energy, subatomic

How does a collider work, explained using various Physics theories (or if there is a main one) . How does the acceleration play a part in the individual sub-atomic kinetic levels. What happens when the particles/protons/ions collide at high velocities that cause them to fuse or how do they even fuse?

Comment: You are asking for a set of courses in experimental and particle physics. better start from the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collider . What happens  when  particles collide is the graduate course for a degree in high energy physics

Comment: I can only agree with @annav, this question is far too broad. One can give a one sentence explanation for what an accelerator/storage ring is, but it's not very helpful: "A particle accelerator/storage ring is a giant transformer with a secondary made from a particle beam."... 400kV go in, 14TV come out. What happens with the accelerated beams... that's basically the level of understanding you can hope for after four years of physics classes plus a PhD, I am afraid.